# dictionary variable formatting in Python's Mysqldb

Tags: python, formatting, mysql-python

i'm trying to use dictionary variable in mysqldb insert statement in python 2.7 :

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO DCPOWERSTATS(TS,TOTALPOWER,ITPOWER,AVAILABLEPOWER,PuE) VALUES (%s %s %s %s %s)",(dict_timestamp[key], dict_ABFeeds[key], dict_ABITLOAD[key], 1400, PuE))
```

and the table is :

```
sql_createpowertable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DCPOWERSTATS  (TS DATETIME ,TOTALPOWER FLOAT,ITPOWER FLOAT, AVAILABLEPOWER FLOAT, PuE FLOAT)''' 

cursor.execute(sql_createpowertable) .
```

when i try this I get the error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '483.9 334.4 1400 1.44706937799043)' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need commas after each `%s` in the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO DCPOWERSTATS(TS,TOTALPOWER,ITPOWER,AVAILABLEPOWER,PuE) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```